# initialize jquery after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of blocks, for each block their is a css change by jquery on mouseover/out.

I have a button that is job is to add one more block to the list.
It do it great! But the new block not respond to the mouseover/out jquery set.

This is my blocks and the add:

```
        <div class='blocks'>
            <div class='block'>
                <div class='block-top'></div>
                Default Text Here
            </div>
            <div class='block'>
                <div class='block-top'></div>
                Default Text Here
            </div>
            <div class='block'>
                <div class='block-top'></div>
                Default Text Here
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href='#' id='addBlock'>Add Block</a>
```

And this is the javascipt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var inEdit=0;
            $(".block").hoverIntent(function() {
                if(inEdit==0) {
                    $(this).children('.block-top').delay(300).animate({opacity:1},600);
                    $(this).delay(300).animate({borderColor: '#8f8f8f'},600);
                }
            },function() {
                if(inEdit==0) {
                    $(this).children('.block-top').animate({opacity:0},200);
                    $(this).animate({borderColor: '#ffffff'},200);
                }
            });
            $('#addBlock').click(function() {
                $('.blocks').append("<div class='block'><div class='block-top'></div>Default Text Here</div>");

            });
        });
```

I'm using this two scripts:
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish that future elements benefits from the event, you have to use `on` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

For instance :

```
$('#addBlock').on('click', function() {
    $('.blocks').append("<div class='block'><div class='block-top'></div>Default Text Here</div>");
});
```

Comment: unless I'm mistaken wouldnt that just benefit the #addBlock element. not add the eventhandler to the new elements?

Comment: `on` will apply the event handler to new element as well.

Comment: While `on()` is the correct way to go, this doesn't answer the question as I understood it. I think they want the div that's added using the `.append()` call to have an event handler assigned to it automatically - the link ('#addBlock') will always be there.

Comment: Just used an example to explain how to use it... the doc explains it all.

Comment: i'm using jQuery v1.7.1. I change the click to $('#addBlock').delegate('click',function() { but I get an error... Object function () {
     $('.blocks').append("<div class='block'><div class='block-top'></div>Default Text Here</div>");
     
    } has no method 'replace'

Comment: And if I use on() it's not change the situation

Comment: You can optimize the sample a lot by passing only the new element. This was made quick and dirty. But glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

make use of jquery live() method, i.e) use below codes

```
$(".block").live('hoverIntent', function() {  //this line is modified
            if(inEdit==0) {
                $(this).children('.block-top').delay(300).animate({opacity:1},600);
                $(this).delay(300).animate({borderColor: '#8f8f8f'},600);
            }
        },function() {
            if(inEdit==0) {
                $(this).children('.block-top').animate({opacity:0},200);
                $(this).animate({borderColor: '#ffffff'},200);
            }
        });
```

make some adjustments to add 2 functions for the event 'hoverIntent'. I mean this will work

```
    $(".block").live('hoverIntent', function() {  //this line is modified
            if(inEdit==0) {
                $(this).children('.block-top').delay(300).animate({opacity:1},600);
                $(this).delay(300).animate({borderColor: '#8f8f8f'},600);
            }
        });
```

but to have 2 functions you can try like

```
    $(".block").live('hoverIntent', function() {  //this line is modified
            if(inEdit==0) {
                $(this).children('.block-top').delay(400).animate({opacity:1},600);
                $(this).delay(400).animate({borderColor: '#8f8f8f'},600);
            }

            if(inEdit==0) {
                $(this).children('.block-top').animate({opacity:0},200);
                $(this).animate({borderColor: '#ffffff'},200);
            }
        });
```

Comment: live adds the event handler to the top of the DOM and is generally frowned against as it can become resource intensive. Delegate() or the new On() method allows you to choose the parent '.blocks' element and apply the event handler to it instead

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on` instead.

Comment: What are the adjustments that I need to do in hoverIntent?

Comment: @DominicGoulet That's only true for jQuery 1.7+, earlier versions should be using `.delegate()`.

Comment: @Nir I have edited 3rd option, Can you try that, if that fails put second if condition in a seperate function and call that function after first if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the hoverintent to the element which doesnt exist on load. Therefore the new element wont get the event handler. You have to use .Delegate() or .on()/.off() depending on your version of jQuery Information on how to use each can be found below

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
http://api.jquery.com/on/

However as hoverIntent uses jquerys mouseover i dont know if it has a specific eventType you can use for delegate/on

Answer (score 0):

This question is about using hoverIntent on new elements. There is exactly this other thread about the same thing, check out the answer :

[help with understanding the logic behind how javascript executes on new dom elements being created on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947341/help-with-understanding-the-logic-behind-how-javascript-executes-on-new-dom-elem)